# Slicing a python variable removes the whole string

Tags: python, substring, slice, cx-oracle

I'm a python newbie, using the `cx_Oracle` python package to execute a sql query:

```
cursor.execute("select tablespace_name from user_tablespaces")
```

to retrieve a list from an oracle 11g database.  The results look like this:

```
('SYSTEM',)
('SYSAUX',)
('UNDOTBS1',)
('TEMP',)
('USERS',)
```

I need to remove the single quotes and the comma from each entry and then put it into an array, and am attempting to use python slicing to do so:

```
tablespaceNames = []
for result in cursor:
    tablespaceNames.append(result[2:-3])
```

however, this is just giving me empty strings in my array:

```
()
()
()
()
```

Is it a problem with the object I'm getting from the query result, or am I using python slicing wrong?

Comment: It's because you only have one item in the tuple... You should be using `result[0]`. You cannot remove the quotes because the value is a string.

Comment: To clarify the terminology, the results are 5 tuples - the trailing comma is a syntactic device for single item tuples.  Your example does not create an array (which you probably don't want) but a *list*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are slicing the tuples that represent each retrieved row rather than the strings that are the first (and only) elements of those rows. Further, you don't need to "get rid of the quotes" - that's just the interpreter doing its best to represent the data structure.

Your database returns the equivalent of the structure below - a list of tuples. Since you only selected a single field, each tuple only contains one element.

```
data = [
    ('SYSTEM',),
    ('SYSAUX',),
    ('UNDOTBS1',),
    ('TEMP',),
    ('USERS',)
]
```

So first let's extract those single elements to give ourselves a list of strings instead of a list of tuples.

```
sdata = [s[0] for s in data]
print(sdata)
```

The output you will see is

```
['SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX', 'UNDOTBS1', 'TEMP', 'USERS']
```

Then print out each of the strings in the tuple:

```
for s in sdata:
    print(s)
```

The output from this code is

```
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS
```

See - no quotes!

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realized I was getting tuple values in the result set but now the behavior makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
tableNameSpaces = [item [0][2:-3] for item in cursor]
```

The quotes will be in, though, since you're dealing with string literals.
Once you print them, however, the quotes will be gone.

As nicarus pointed out to me, probably you don't want to truncate your string literals at all, though I thought that's what you wanted.

In that case it would simply be:

```
tableNameSpaces = [item [0] for item in cursor]
```

Comment: I think the slicing was only there to try to remove the quotes and comma, so it may not apply here anymore. Your solution would truncate each value.

Comment: That is probably indeed what qwix meant, I'll add it!